# LINQ Left Join with Grouping and Having Convert this TSQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

The following TSQL provides an example of how I might solve this problem with SQL.  The goal is to return 1 row per OID from the Left Table, where the Count of the records in the left table is equal to the Count of the matching rows in the right table.

```
SELECT cs.OID, Count(cs.OID) AS CarCount, Sum(RS.Check) AS RoadCount  
   FROM Cars AS cs  
LEFT JOIN Roads AS RS  
  ON CS.oid = RS.OID  
   AND cs.RID = RS.RID  
  GROUP BY cs.OID  
  HAVING Count(cs.OID) = Sum(RS.Check)
```

Using object setup below, is there an equivalent LINQ query that can be constructed, or is this not possible?  Note the default value given for check in the declaration of the Road class.  In the setup example below the result should be zero matching.  Adding one more road with proper values will have it return just one. At least that is what is ideal.

The problem I have run into is that it seems this type of TSQL code is just too complex for LINQ.  I haven't found an obvious or non-obvious solution to achieve a similar behavior.  Thus I believe perhaps the solution is to stop trying to copy SQL and do something different.  With not enough LINQ experience, I wouldn't know where to start.

```
public class Roads : List<Road>{}  
public class Road  
{  
    public int RID;  
    public int OID;  
    public int check = 1;  
}  
public class Cars : List<Car> { }  
public class Car  
{  
    public int RID;  
    public int OID;  
}  

private void CheckCheck()  
{  
    Roads rs = new Roads();  
    Cars cs = new Cars();  

    Car c = new Car();  
    c.OID = 1;  
    c.RID = 1;  
    cs.Add(c);  
    c = new Car();  
    c.OID = 1;  
    c.RID = 2;  
    cs.Add(c);  
    c = new Car();  
    c.OID = 1;  
    c.RID = 3;  
    cs.Add(c);  

    Road r = new Road();  
    r.OID = 1;  
    r.RID = 1;  
    rs.Add(r);  
    r = new Road();  
    r.OID = 1;  
    r.RID = 2;  
    rs.Add(r);  

    // Results should be :  
    // OID where Count of OID from C = Count of OID from R  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your HAVING clause would filter out any cars which do not match roads.  This makes the left join into an inner join.
- You have `COUNT(cs.OID)` which says it's counting cars, but it doesn't.  You might have meant `COUNT(DISTINCT cs.OID)`

Here's a literal translation:

```
from c in Cars
join r in Roads on new {c.OID, c.RID} equals new {r.OID, r.RID}
group new {Car = c, Road = r} by c.OID into g
let carCount = g.Count()  //did you mean g.Select(x => x.Car.OID).Distinct().Count()
let roadCount = g.Sum(x => x.Road.Check)
where carCount = roadCount
select new {OID = g.Key, CarCount = carCount, RoadCount = roadCount}
```

---

> The goal is to return 1 row per OID from the Left Table, where the Count of the records in the left table is equal to the Count of the matching rows in the right table.

Based on this description, I'd write:

```
var carLookup = Cars.ToLookup(c => c.OID);
var roadLookup = Roads.ToLookup(r => r.OID);

from x in carLookup
let carCount = x.Count()
let roadCount = roadLookup[x.Key].Count()
where carCount = roadCount
select new {OID = g.Key, CarCount = carCount, RoadCount = roadCount}
```

Comment: Nice use of Lookups. I always overlook that method.

Comment: I will give it a try and feedback.  This sample was simplified version of more complex query but has the particular trouble spots.  Note cs.OID is unique in Cars, so no need for distinct.  The idea being I have 3 rows in the left table, and I want to return a row only if I also have a matching 3 rows in the right table.  Thus the Count(CS.OID) and the SUM(rs.check) - in SQL, rs.check will be null for non matches, and SQL ignores nulls in the sum.

Comment: If you join... cs.OID will not be unique in the result.  And since you're ignoring the nulls, you don't need LEFT JOIN to make nulls for you to ignore.

Comment: Hmm, with the first example I am getting an error 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Road' does not contain a definition for 'Check' and no extension method 'Check' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Road' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?  with a blue sqwigle under the word Check in this: Line : let roadCount = g.Sum(x => x.Road.Check).  I'll do some more playing tomorrow.  Thank you all.

Comment: Getting close, and I will play with your examples perhaps finding a solution on my own. Issues with the examples above.  #1 - using the object set in the original question this returns a single row with OID = 1, CarCount =2, RoadCount = 2. Yes, they both have 2, but CarCount should be 3.  Thus the left join.  #2 - Results in a message At least one object must implement IComparable.  The left join seems to be the sticking point here.

Comment: Revised result for #2 -   g.key isn't valid, so I had done something different causing the message.  Removing the OID from the result completely, results in #2 giving me no result, if the carcount and roadcount are not equal, and a single row, with CarCount = 3 and RowCount=3 if I add one road.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what the desired results are but here's my shot at it.  The `check` field isn't really necessary with LINQ as it doesn't serve any purpose other than for counting.

I misunderstood the importance of the join and what the `HAVING` clause did for the query.  It's now back to the original TSQL version but with the changed `RoadCount` calculation.  I believe this is what you were asking for.

```
var results = from Car in cs
              join road in rs
                  on new { Car.OID, Car.RID } equals new { road.OID, road.RID }
                  into Roads
              group roads by Car.OID into cars
              let CarCount = cars.Count()
              let RoadCount = cars.Sum(roads => roads.Count())
              where CarCount == RoadCount
              select new
              {
                  OID = cars.Key,
                  CarCount,
                  RoadCount
              };
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  With your example, I end up with two rows.  Each containing.  OID = 1, CarCount = 1, RoadCount = 1.  With the data in the sample above, results should be empty as there are 3 cars and 2 roads.  But if we didn't rely on the HAVING, if we just return the left join, it would be a single row with OID = 1, CarCount = 3, Roadcount = 2.   If I could achieve that, it would be a positive move forward.

Comment: @Mike: Right, it would yield two rows since we joined by matching both `OID` and `RID`.  Since the result only includes the `OID`, they look identical since we left out the `RID`.  But that was based on my interpretation of your TSQL code.  Now that I have a better idea of the desired results, it appears we should be grouping and joining just on `OID`.

Comment: We can't just group on OID.  We need to group on RID and OID, as that is what makes a match.  The catch is that we need to find the grouping of RID + OID where there are matches for all rows in cars.  For example.  If I am building an assembly.  The assembly will have 3 components.  To know if the built assembly is correct, we must compare the build to the rules.  One way to do this, and the SQL shows this) is to left join the build into the rules.  If the rules are made up of 3 components, but the build was only made up from 2 components it is a failed build. (in this case a null result)

Comment: I should note that the previous version I had was equivalent to David's Lookup version (which turns out to be what you ended up using).  Neither joined nor grouped by both `RID` and `OID` so I'm at a loss for what you are trying to accomplish.  Although now, my latest revision makes it equivalent to his literal translation.

Comment: Looks good.  Thank you.  I'm a bit at a loss as well.  This was really just a first part.  There is more that I need to do.  The goal of this is to replicate the behavior of the TSQL in the post.  I've expanded this question into further detail here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179550/left-join-linq-and-using-bitwise-comparisons